# "Am I not correct" or "Am not I correct" - which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> 1. "Am I not correct "
> 2. "Am not I correct "

Which of the above expression it correct and if both of them are wrong then what is the correct expression? 
 And I am referring to a statement

Comment: It might make a difference whether you are referring to a question or a statement. *Am I not correct* would be unusual wording for a statement.

Comment: The second example sounds horrible to my ears, but I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out to be grammatically correct.

Comment: @AlanCarmack  yes I am referring to a statement

Comment: If you are not asking a question, the ordinary word order is *I am not correct.* If you are asking a question, *Am I not correct?* would be typical.

Comment: Raunit, in English it's important to end each statement with a period (.). Otherwise, what you write becomes unclear. Also, one ends a question with a question mark (?).

Comment: Could you search for and add some examples using each? What you find might answer your question, but if not will help others answer rather than guess at what you mean.

Comment: @AlanCarmack  I mean I made a statement in which I am little confused wreathe I made a correct statement or not.  so I am asking the listener weather it is correct or not . so in  such case what should I say the to listener to ask him weather I am correct or not. And I personally believe that my statement is correct and just to get his approval I am asking  this question

Comment: Context would be important here but overall you'll hear "incorrect" probably more often than "not correct".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply, the scenario is

- you made a statement;
- you assume the statement is correct;
- you want a confirmation or denial from the listener.

In that case you should *ask*

> Am I not correct?

Or

> Am I incorrect?

But not "*Am not I correct" - that would be, well, an incorrect way to ask the question.

Comment: So, playing the Devil's advocate here, what would "Ain't I correct" be the contraction of?

Comment: *Aren't I right/correct?* would also be standard English. I thought of *Ain't I right/correct?* but didn't want to confuse Raunit with "non-standard" *ain't*. @MrLister

Comment: The OP did not ask about the contacted forms (and contractions in first person are a different long discussion...). This is a good example of the fact that these so-called "contractions" are trickier than they seem. "Isn't it so" cannot be expanded to "*is not it so" - the corrrect structure is "is it not so".